# Create an array of random numbers and return the array in C

Tags: c

I want to create a function called get_lotto_draw that will create an array of 6 random numbers and return them to main.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    get_lotto_draw()
    {
        int lottery[50];
        int u,i,j,temp;
        int lotto[6];

        srand(time(NULL));
            for (i =0; i<49; i++)
                lottery[i] = i+1;


            for (i =0; i<49; i++)
            {
                j = (rand()%49)+1;

                temp = lottery[i];
                lottery[i] = lottery[j];
                lottery[j] = temp;
            }

                for (i =0; i<6; i++)    
                {
                    lotto[i] = lottery[i];
                }

            return lotto;           
    }
```

Comment: you forgot to ask an explicit question!

Comment: There are several problems with the function you show: First and foremost is that you do not declare a return-type, so the compiler will make it `int`. Also, if you change it to return a pointer then you're returning a pointer to a local variable which will go out of scope once the function returns and leave you with a stray pointer. And don't call `srand` in the function, it will reset the seed every time you call the function, so if you call it twice (or more) in the same second both calls will generate the same "random" numbers.

Comment: All in all, the compiler should be screaming if not errors then warnings at you. Read them!

Comment: fix your formatting! It is not just whitespace, its the cause of bugs!

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `get_lotto_draw()` --> `int *get_lotto_draw(void)`, `int lotto[6];` --> `int *lotto=malloc(sizeof(int[6]));`

Comment: btw check out fisher-yates for a better algorithm to shuffle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



  void get_lotto_draw(int lotto[])
    {
        int lottery[50];
        int u,i,j,temp;

        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
            lottery[i] = i+1;


        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
        {
            j = (rand()%49)+1;

            temp = lottery[i];
            lottery[i] = lottery[j];
            lottery[j] = temp;
        }

            for (i =0; i<6; i++)    
            {
                lotto[i] = lottery[i];
            }

        return ;           
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        int lotto[6];

    srand(time(NULL));

    get_lotto_draw(lotto);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
        printf ("%d ", lotto[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The  function `get_lotto_draw` will take the array 'lotto' as an argument - unsized array. 
If you declare lotto as auto variable inside the function then when the function ends - the auto variable  lotto would have been removed - check this [link](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml) for details. 
So you declare lotto in main and pass it to the function.

Other options include

- use malloc (to allocate memory for 'lotto') inside the get_lotto_draw and free in main (unless you are very careful- this will lead to memory leaks - I do not recommend this)
- use malloc in main and pass the allocated memory to the function and free it in main later
- create a static and use it.

My recommendation is in such situations to use the stack (auto variable as used above)  otherwise use malloc/free.

I fixed some of the bugs others pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for everyone who helped. I spent a few hours reading and learning about the things you mentioned. I have now managed to create a piece of code that will do what I wanted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int *get_lotto_draw(int n)
    {
        int i;
        int *lotto;

        lotto = malloc(n * sizeof(*lotto));
        if (lotto == NULL) 
            return NULL;


        int lottery[50];
        int u,j,temp;

        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
            lottery[i] = i+1;


        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
        {
            j = (rand()%49)+1;

            temp = lottery[i];
            lottery[i] = lottery[j];
            lottery[j] = temp;
        }

            for (i =0; i<6; i++)    
            {
                lotto[i] = lottery[i];
            }

        return lotto;           
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i, n = 6;
    int *lotto;

    srand(time(NULL));

    lotto = get_lotto_draw(n);
    if (lotto == NULL) 
        return -1;

    printf("Here is the array: ");
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { 
        printf("%d ", lotto[i]); 
    }
    free(lotto); 
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: call the `malloc` in main - it is a good practice to have the function that calls `malloc` to also do the `free`.

Comment: BTW, If my previous answer gave you guidance and answered your question - please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that I can do this by using static int as I have an array of set length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int *get_lotto_draw(int n)
    {
        int i;
        static int lotto[6];

        int lottery[50];
        int u,j,temp;

        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
            lottery[i] = i+1;


        for (i =0; i<49; i++)
        {
            j = (rand()%49)+1;

            temp = lottery[i];
            lottery[i] = lottery[j];
            lottery[j] = temp;
        }

            for (i =0; i<6; i++)    
            {
                lotto[i] = lottery[i];
            }

        return lotto;           
    }



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i, n = 6;
    int *lotto;

    srand(time(NULL));

    lotto = get_lotto_draw(n);


    printf("Here is the array: ");
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { 
        printf("%d ", lotto[i]); 
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```